# How can I distinguish music from non-music in the SoundCloud tracks API?

Tags: api, audio, soundcloud

I'm trying to analyze track data from many artists. How can I tell if a track record obtained from the Tracks API (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) is music vs. non-music?

To understand what I mean, you can look at the SoundCloud Explore page: https://soundcloud.com/explore. On the left sidebar, there are two major groups of genre:

Music:

```
Jazz & Blues
Urban
Pop
Reggae
Metal
Rock
Electronic
Classical
World
```

Audio (non-music):

```
Sports
Learning
Books
Storytelling
Business & Technology
Comedy
News
Arts & Entertainment
```

How can I tell from data retrieved in the Tracks API is in the "Music" group or in the "Audio" group? The closest possibilities I can see are the track_type and the genre fields, but neither of these clearly maps into the groupings I see on the Explore page.

Answer (score 2):

The grouping of those tracks aren't exposed through the API at the moment, so I'd say `track_type` and `genre` are your best bet. There's a number of different track types (you can find them on a track's edit page), but I guess if you want to distinguish between audio and music I guess `podcast`, `spoken`, `original` or `remix` are most relevant. Then I guess you could also look at the genre.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But is there somewhere where all the possible track_type options are explained? For example, "original" doesn't tell me whether it is spoken audio or music. Is any further documentation available?

Comment: Not really, they are indeed a bit vague, they are also not documented in the UI that people use to set this attribute. I'm gonna see what the plans are for `track_type` as we're not doing a whole lot with it anymore.